# (Py)Qt: QSortFilterProxyModel calls index() with parent from wrong model

Tags: qt, model, pyqt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I'm having an odd problem with a `QSortFilterProxyModel`. I do this in my QTreeView:

```python
class CompletionView(QTreeView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setModel(QSortFilterProxyModel())

        m1 = CompletionModel()
        print("Model 1: {}".format(m1))
        m1.init_data({'test1': [('one', 'two'), ('three', 'four')]})
        self.model().setSourceModel(m1)
        self.expandAll()

        m2 = CompletionModel()
        print("Model 2: {}".format(m2))
        m2.init_data({'test': [('five', 'six'), ('seven', 'eight')]})
        self.model().setSourceModel(m2)
        self.expandAll()
```

This is my CompletionModel, which I couldn't really simplify more:

```python
class CompletionModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._id_map = {}
        self._root = CompletionItem([""] * 2)
        self._id_map[id(self._root)] = self._root

    def _node(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return self._id_map[index.internalId()]
        else:
            return self._root

    def init_data(self, data):
        for (cat, items) in data.items():
            newcat = CompletionItem([cat], self._root)
            self._id_map[id(newcat)] = newcat
            self._root.children.append(newcat)
            for item in items:
                newitem = CompletionItem(item, newcat)
                self._id_map[id(newitem)] = newitem
                newcat.children.append(newitem)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self._root.column_count()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if parent.column() > 0:
            return 0

        if not parent.isValid():
            pitem = self._root
        else:
            pitem = self._id_map[parent.internalId()]
        return len(pitem.children)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant()
        try:
            item = self._id_map[index.internalId()]
        except KeyError:
            return QVariant()
        try:
            return QVariant(item.data(index.column(), role))
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            return QVariant()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(self._root.data(section))
        return QVariant()

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if parent.model() is not None and parent.model() is not self:
            raise ValueError("Model mismatch: parentmodel {}, self {}".format(parent.model(), self))
        if (0 <= row < self.rowCount(parent) and
                0 <= column < self.columnCount(parent)):
            pass
        else:
            return QModelIndex()

        if not parent.isValid():
            parent_item = self._root
        else:
            parent_item = self._id_map[parent.internalId()]

        child_item = parent_item.children[row]
        if child_item:
            index = self.createIndex(row, column, id(child_item))
            self._id_map.setdefault(index.internalId(), child_item)
            return index
        else:
            return QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()
        item = self._id_map[index.internalId()].parent
        if item == self._root or item is None:
            return QModelIndex()
        return self.createIndex(item.row(), 0, id(item))


class CompletionItem():
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []
        self._data = data

    def data(self, column, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[column]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid role {}".format(role))

    def column_count(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def row(self):
        if self.parent:
            return self.parent.children.index(self)
        return 0
```

Note I raise a `ValueError` in `index()` if I get a wrong parent.

Now when I execute my example script (pasted [in my pastebin](http://paste.the-compiler.org/view/f64d440a)), this happens:

```
Model 1: <__main__.CompletionModel object at 0x7fefe1ccd770>
Model 2: <__main__.CompletionModel object at 0x7fefe1ccd808>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 59, in index
    raise ValueError("Model mismatch: parentmodel {}, self {}".format(parent.model(), self))
ValueError: Model mismatch: parentmodel <__main__.CompletionModel object at 0x7fefe1ccd770>, self <__main__.CompletionModel object at 0x7fefe1ccd808>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 59, in index
    raise ValueError("Model mismatch: parentmodel {}, self {}".format(parent.model(), self))
ValueError: Model mismatch: parentmodel <__main__.CompletionModel object at 0x7fefe1ccd770>, self <__main__.CompletionModel object at 0x7fefe1ccd808>
```

Why does this happen? Do I do something wrong in my model, or is this a Qt bug?

I also tried to use `None` as a sentinel value where I use `QModelIndex()` as default value for a function parameter (although it shouldn't be modified, so it shouldn't be an issue), that didn't help.

Comment: In index() method: Is it okay to use local variable named "index" same as name of method?

Comment: @yshurik Good catch, but that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Also in cinstructor of CompletionView, you call m1.init_data when I guess you wanted m2.init_data

Answer (score 2):

There are probably some references being held somewhere for the previous model when you reset it, and so you get the "Model Mismatch" errors.

When I tried your example, I found that setting the source model to `None` between resets eliminates the errors:

```
    self.model().setSourceModel(m1)
    ...
    self.model().setSourceModel(None) # clear the current model
    ...
    self.model().setSourceModel(m2)
```

Comment: That's a working workaround indeed. However I still wonder if this is a bug in my model I haven't spotted yet, or if it's a bug in Qt and I should open a bugreport. Though a pure C++ testcase would be handy.

Comment: @TheCompiler. I haven't looked at your model in any detail, but I don't see any obvious reason to suspect a bug. These kinds of issues come up all the time in PyQt, because every object has two aspects: the Python part and the Qt part. Quite often, you will need to explicitly delete things (and in the right order), rather than relying on the garbage-collector to tidy up for you. This is especially true with models in item-views (see the docs for [setModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setModel) for more details).

Answer (score -2):

Just remembered why you have this problem.

Actually it is Python especiality of method arguments with default value.
Python especiality is that such argument is static_variable.
So when first time it was a call:

m1.index(1,2,parent_from_model_m1);

and later just call:

m2.index(3,4)

then for second call the "parent" will get default value - not QModelIndex() but parent_from_model_m1 ("parent" argument as static variable remembered parent_from_model_m1 from first call)

Solution should be simple - remove default values.

Comment: This is not how default arguments work in python. Default arguments are not reset every time they are called. The default is set _once_ when the class statement is executed. So whenever `index(row, column)` is called, the `parent` argument is always the _same_ instance of `QModelIndex`.